# Cannot align fontawesome icons on sidebar

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, alignment, font-awesome

I'm having some real trouble trying to align icons within their divs. Nothing I try works whether it be creating custom CSS or trying to use bootstrap's text-align-center.

Here's a cut down example of the navbar:

```
<div id="appSidenav" class="sidenav">
    <button class="closebtn btn" id="navClose" onclick="closeNav()"><i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i></button>
    <button class="openbtn btn" id="navOpen" onclick="openNav()"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></button>
    <a href="#" class="pt-3">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-2">
                <i class="fas fa-home"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <span>Home</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-2">
                <i class="fas fa-users"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <span>Contacts</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

I've tried to add text-center to the cols, I've also tried adding `text-align: center;` to the CSS but nothing seems to make any difference. I've also tried different sized cols and cols with no padding or margin.

I've tried adding an alignment to pretty much every tag or class and nothing works.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

UPDATE

Nobody seems to quite understand what I'm getting at, so I'll post a picture.

I've tried to align the icons using both CSS and bootstrap classes. I can live with it I guess but it's a bit annoying. Here's what's happening:

[image]

Comment: please share live code.

Comment: I don't understand, what you mean exactly, Can you take a photo of what you want to output with Paint?

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand what you mean exactly,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Font Awesome 5 Icons</title>
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
<script src='https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js'></script>
<!--Get your own code at fontawesome.com-->
</head>
<body>

<div id="appSidenav" class="sidenav">
    <button class="closebtn btn" id="navClose" onclick="closeNav()"><i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i></button>
    <button class="openbtn btn" id="navOpen" onclick="openNav()"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></button>
    <a href="#" class="pt-3">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-2">
                <i class="fas fa-home"></i>  <span>Home</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-2">
                <i class="fas fa-users"></i> <span>Contacts</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to center align them, you can:

- try `text-align: center` on the parent/wrapper of the item you are trying to center align
- another method is to add `display: flex` to the parent/wrapper and `margin: auto` to the item you are trying to center align.

Answer (score -1):

i assume that you want to center align a link... If so i think u are supposed to add "a" after the div class in css... I will take home for exmaple.

I think the css should look something like,

`.col a{ text-align:cenetr; }`

Hopefully it helps.. thx